# PowerShell synchronization with reg.exe

Tags: powershell, synchronization, registry

I want to set the same values for a large number of registry keys, so I created a PowerShell 2.0 script, to iterate through these keys.

The PowerShell script:

```
function Main {
    param (
        [ Parameter( Mandatory = $true ) ] $ScriptInvocation
    )
    RequireElevation -ScriptInvocation $ScriptInvocation
    $ScriptFolder = Split-Path -Parent $ScriptInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
    Push-Location -Path $ScriptFolder
    ApplyVariants
    Pop-Location
}

function RequireElevation {
    param (
        [ Parameter( Mandatory = $true ) ] $ScriptInvocation
    )
    $CurrentIdentity = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
    $CurrentPrincipal = [Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] $CurrentIdentity
    $AdministratorRole = [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator
    if( -not $CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole( $AdministratorRole ) ) {
        $ScriptPath = $ScriptInvocation.MyCommand.Path
        Start-Process -FilePath 'powershell.exe' -ArgumentList '-File', """$ScriptPath""" -Verb RunAs
        Exit
    }
}

function ApplyVariants {
    ApplyVariant -RegFilePath '.\Folder View Per TopView.reg' -Change @{ `
        OldString = '{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'; `
        NewString = '{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}' }
    ApplyVariant -RegFilePath '.\Folder View Per TopView.reg' -Change @{ `
        OldString = '{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'; `
        NewString = '{5f4eab9a-6833-4f61-899d-31cf46979d49}\TopViews\{77f0bfb4-6aa3-440b-9f6d-1c147467806d}' }
    ApplyVariant -RegFilePath '.\Folder View Per TopView.reg' -Change @{ `
        OldString = '{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'; `
        NewString = '{5f4eab9a-6833-4f61-899d-31cf46979d49}\TopViews\{82ba0782-5b7a-4569-b5d7-ec83085f08cc}' }
    ApplyVariant -RegFilePath '.\Folder View Per TopView.reg' -Change @{ `
        OldString = '{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'; `
        NewString = '{5f4eab9a-6833-4f61-899d-31cf46979d49}\TopViews\{92d203dc-8565-4902-b92c-eaaa54d7364a}' }
    # And many, many more ...
}

function ApplyVariant {
    param (
        [ Parameter( Mandatory = $true ) ] $RegFilePath,
        [ Parameter( Mandatory = $true ) ] $Change
    )
    $TmpFilePath = '.\TemporaryFileCreatedByPowerShell.reg'
    $OriginalText = Get-Content -Path $RegFilePath
    $VariantText = $OriginalText -replace [Regex]::Escape( $Change.OldString ), $Change.NewString
    Set-Content -Path $TmpFilePath -Value $VariantText
    # I hope the file is saved before this line
    UpdateRegistry -RegFilePath $TmpFilePath
    # I hope the file is not required after this line
    Remove-Item -Path $TmpFilePath
}

function UpdateRegistry {
    param (
        [ Parameter( Mandatory = $true ) ] $RegFilePath
    )
    # Does this really wait?
    Start-Process -FilePath 'reg.exe' -ArgumentList 'import', """$RegFilePath""" -Wait
}

Main -ScriptInvocation $MyInvocation
```

The values I want to set are in this .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TopViews\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}]
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=-
"IconSize"=-
"HideFileNames"=-
"ColumnList"="prop:0(34)System.ItemNameDisplay;0System.Size;0System.DateModified;0System.DateCreated"
"SortByList"="prop:System.ItemNameDisplay"
"GroupBy"=-
"GroupAscending"=-
"StackBy"=-
"DateCategorizerInfo"=-
"PrimaryProperty"=-
```

When I run this script, I get no error message. (Even if I add a `-NoExit` argument to PowerShell's command line.)

However, for some of the keys, the values are not set after running the script. But if I comment out lines in `ApplyVariants`, and run each line alone, the values for the given key are set.

I suspect that there is some synchronization issue. Maybe the files are deleted before reg.exe could read them.

Is `-Wait` enough to wait for reg.exe to finish? What can cause this issue?

Comment: You should check the exit status of the `reg.exe` process. Some of them could fail due to key locks by running process (like `explorer.exe`...). It's also possible that some running deamons may prevent changes like the Java helper plugin for Java keys. I suggest you to use sysinternal tools to check every processes accessing theses keys. I suggest you also to update the registry in one shot and not for each keys (build a reg file and import the file only at end of the process).